# MySQLi prepare statement failing with error: Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've update the question to further clarify

This is my first time dealing with MySQLi inserts. I had always used MySQL and directly ran the queries. Apparently, not as secure as MySQLi.

Anyhow, I’m attempting to pass two variables into the database. For some reason my prepared statement fails to do anything.

Edit: IT WORKSSS NOWWWW!!!!  I added in wayyyyy more error checking. Took a bit of research, but adding checks into each function. That way I find the error code corresponding to the correct function. Once again, thank you for all your help. SURELY wouldn't of done this without you. The code listed below is now the working code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
function InsertIPs($decimnal,$cidr)
{
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","jeremysd_ips","","jeremysd_ips");
       if(mysqli_connect_errno())
       {
          echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
          exit();
       }
            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO subnets VALUES ('',?,?,'1','','0','0','0','0','0', '', '0', '0', NULL)");
            if( false===$stmt ){
            die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
            }
            $rc = $stmt->bind_param('ii',$decimnal,$cidr);
            if( false===$rc ){
                        die('bind_param() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                        }


            $rc=$stmt->execute();
            if( false===$rc ){
                        die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
                        }
            printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

            $stmt->close();

            $mysqli -> close();
}

$SUBNETS = array ("2915483648 | 18");

foreach($SUBNETS as $Ip)
{
                list($TempIP,$TempMask) = explode(' | ',$Ip);
        echo InsertIPs($TempIP,$TempMask);
}

?>
```

Thank you again

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: 90% of PHP/MySQL queries on [so] don't bother to check the return status of their MySQL calls, and when they do they don't check the error message. If you checked the error messages that MySQL gives you you'd probably already know what's wrong here.

Comment: @Fred-ii- the last comment is incorrect. Those variables are fine, Look close

Comment: There could be some `room` for error but technically those variable names are being used correctly and being passed correctly and there is no mistmatch. `Variable mismatch` only this part of your comment is incorrect imho.

Comment: The variables themselves are fine. I can update them to make it easier to read. The error is specifically, Error preparing statement. I will check the error message by mysql. I'm not sure how to do that, but I will find out

Comment: Here http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Here, use this instead. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` it will show you exactly where the error is. You'll most likely get something like  `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '3':'1','2':'2'}')' at line 1' in /home/user/pub/file.php:xx Stack trace: #0 /home/user/pub/file.php(xx): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO for...') #1 {main} thrown in...`

Comment: *"As they need to appear in the database as: {"3":"1","2":"2"}"* -  Here's your answer: Use `'{\"3\":\"1\",\"2\":\"2\"}'` it will appear as `{"3":"1","2":"2"}` in DB. Least it has for me.

Comment: Thank you for the lesson. I found the syntax errors and I'm working through them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your pure query:

```
"INSERT INTO subnets
(id, subnet, mask,sectionId,description,vrfld,masterSubnetId,allowRequests,vlanId,showName,permissions,pingSubnet,isFolder,editDate)
VALUES
('',?,?,'1','','0','0','0','0','0', '{'3':'1','2':'2'}', '0', '0', NULL)"
```

What is that `'{'3':'1','2':'2'}'` which has a comma in it? Should that be reformatted so the MySQL query doesn’t choke on it? Should those values be escaped like this:

```
'{\'3\':\'1\',\'2\':\'2\'}'
```

Or perhaps with `"` since you seem to now indicate you need double quotes?

```
'{\"3\":\"1\",\"2\":\"2\"}'
```

Because the single quotes mixed in with that comma just seem problematic.

Or another solution is to just bind that value to the query like this:

```
$raw_query = "INSERT INTO subnets (id, subnet, mask, sectionId, description, vrfld, masterSubnetId, allowRequests, vlanId, showName, permissions, pingSubnet, isFolder, editDate)
VALUES ('',?,?,'1','','0','0','0','0','0',?, '0', '0', NULL)";
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare($raw_query))
{
    $stmt-> bind_param('ii',$decimnal,$cidr,$cidr,'{"3":"1","2":"2"}');
```